# Vuejs: How to make this if else as Boolean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, boolean

I have a component with buttons that show some elements (v-autocomplete) when we click on them, but I should make it with a Boolean to simplify the code, how can I do that?

Because actually, it adds the index of the item in one array in showCompetence state, but I just would like a Boolean on each index Basically at the "openCompetence" function in "Methods".

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    name: "SkillCvCard",
    data() {
        return {
            selectedCompetence: []
        }
    },
    updated() {
        this.addSelectSkill(this.userCompetences.competences.list);
        console.log(this.selectedSkills)
    },
props: {
        userCompetences: {
            type: Array
        },
        showCompetence: {
            type: Array
        }
    },

computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["selectedSkills"]),
        console: () => console,
    },

methods: {
...mapActions(['addSelectSkill']),
openCompetence(index) {
    if (this.showCompetence.includes(index)) {
        console.log("close")
        this.showCompetence.splice(this.showCompetence.indexOf(index), 1)
    } else {
        this.showCompetence.push(index)
        console.log("open")
    }

    console.log(this.showCompetence)
}
}
```

about the template I will just add the minimum I hope it will be ok:

The first is where we click, to launch the "openCompetence" function.

```
<div v-for="(competences, index) of userCompetences.competences" :key="index">
        {{ competences.category }} <v-btn @click="openCompetence(index)"> Add </v-btn>
</div>
```

the rest is a `v-container` with a `v-for` including multiple `v-autocomplete`, but the most important inside is the `v-if`:

```
<div class="skill-field" v-for="(skill, index) of userCompetences.competences" :key="index">
                                <template>
                                <v-flex md12 sm12 xs12 v-if="skill.list.length>0">
                                    <v-autocomplete
                                    v-if="showCompetence.includes(index)"
                                    v-model="userCompetences.competences.list"
                                    :items="skill.list"
                                    chips
                                    hide-selected
                                    :label="skill.category"
                                    item-text="name"
                                    item-value="name"
                                    multiple
                                    >
</v-autocomplete>
</v-flex>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Computed property?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use a computed property to solve a problem like this. However, because you are inside of a `v-for`, a computed property is a little more difficult since you can't evaluate it in the context of each value of the `v-for`'s `index`.

There are two common options:

1. Do exactly what you are doing. It's actually no less efficient since it will not re-evaluate unless data it depends on changes.
2. Add a computed called something like `competencesDisplayState` that returns an array of booleans that matches the ordering of the `userCompetences.competences` array in the `v-for`. Then your v-if can become something like:

```
v-if="competencesDisplayState[index]"
```

I normally just opt for the first approach as it is simpler and is easier to read and maintain.

If you want to go route 2, here's some code for the competencesDisplayState computed:

```
        competencesDisplayState: () => {
            var result = [];
            for (var index=0;index < this.userCompetences.competences.length;++index) {
                result(this.showCompetence.includes(index));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I wanted to try to do your second solution and wanted to start to write the code in "computed" but i didn't know where to start. but i should write a new state in the component, right ? 

Thanks !

Comment: So to write this computed i have to add this in a function ? Like in computed :
test(index) {
the code you wrote
}

and how about to run this function? it shoulds load automaticly ? 
Cause i have nothing when i put that v-if="competenvesDisplayState[index]"

You can see the component here : https://codepen.io/jervalles/pen/NWqwWKB

My code works but i really wanna understand how computed works. Thanks!

Comment: First, I don't think codepen supports .vue components. See an example like this of a working Vue pen: https://codepen.io/bluesmy/pen/poJdJZO Second, I've updated the code above to match more of what you would need.